# Need to select a frame in gif

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox, gif, animated-gif

I need to restart a gif image so it will start from the first frame.
I have little experience with gif images in C#. I work on a C# windows form application. My gif image is in a picturebox. I need to restart it each time a person for example presses a button.

I have tried doing:

```
pictureBox1.Image.SelectActiveFrame(new FrameDimension(pictureBox1.Image.FrameDimensionsList[0]), 0)
```

but it didnt show any change.

I also tried Image animator also no luck. I really need help it is for my final project in high school engineering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried this solution and It's working fine :

```
Image animated = pictureBox1.Image;
pictureBox1.Image = animated;
```

this way , you reset `pictureBox1.Image` so the animated GIF starts from beginning.

Comment: You don't need to set it to null first, just set to the `animated` in one line of code and it does works. I've tested :)

Comment: nothing, that's just better for those who will encounter this problem. In fact, I would like to find another way in case such as not restart to the first frame but the second or third ... That would be the most general way. But it seems to not exist.

Comment: About your update, have you tested with `pictureBox1.Image = pictureBox1.Image;`? It doesn't seem to work. The current frame will be frozen a little while and the next frames continues after that.

Comment: that's odd , but I guess I've found a way for the general case I'll update my answer after testing it

Comment: yes! thank you very much it works great with the [animated]! @Mehran

Comment: I'm glad I could help so please consider choosing this answer as your question's answer , thanks

Answer (score 4):

I found that `Image.SelectActiveFrame()` doesn't seem to work because how it works is not what you thought. It just set the initial frame if there is some control reading its frame, the first frame read is the active frame. So after `SelectActiveFrame()` you have to re-assign the `Image` property of your pictureBox to that new Image, like this:

```
private void RestartToFrameIndex(int index){
   pictureBox.Image.SelectActiveFrame(new FrameDimension(pictureBox.Image.FrameDimensionsList[0]), index);
   pictureBox.Image = pictureBox.Image;
}

//If you want to restart to the first frame, just call the method above like this:
RestartToFrameIndex(0);
```

That's the general solution I've just found :) hope it helps others...

Comment: did it work for you ? I can't make it work for other frames like 10 or 20 `pictureBox.Image = (Image)pictureBox.Image.Clone();` resets the image to frame 0 every time !

Comment: I've tested and it worked, because your Image FrameCount may be less than 10. My code doesn't check the FrameCount, but if so a generic GDI exception will throw, what about 3,4,5? just 10 or 20?