# How to synchronize picturebox images

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-interface, reflection

In my winforms application written in C#, I need to synchronize the timing of 2 GIF-images placed on 2 pictureboxes. That means, one picturebox has one animated GIF-image and the second picturebox has the same animated GIF-image, but with different colors. Both images have to be displayed in the same frame-sequence, when the second picturebox appears.

Based on King King's answer in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17008254/need-to-select-a-frame-in-gif), I implemented this extension methods:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void _buttonTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _pictureBox2.Visible = !_pictureBox2.Visible;

        if (_pictureBox2.Visible)
            _pictureBox2.SynchronizeWith(_pictureBox1);
    }
}

public static class PictureBoxServices
{
    public static void SetPictureFrameIndex(this PictureBox pictureBox, int index)
    {
        pictureBox.Image.SelectActiveFrame(new FrameDimension(pictureBox.Image.FrameDimensionsList[0]), index);
        pictureBox.Image = pictureBox.Image;    // restart on selected index
    }

    public static int GetPictureFrameIndex(this PictureBox pictureBox)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public static void SynchronizeWith(this PictureBox pictureBoxThis, PictureBox pictureBoxToSynchronizeWith)
    {
        pictureBoxThis.SetPictureFrameIndex(pictureBoxToSynchronizeWith.GetPictureFrameIndex());
    }
}
```

I have 2 problems:

1. I dont know how to implement GetPictureFrameIndex
2. SetPictureFrameIndex is not working. It sets and displays the selected frame, but the next displayed frame is always with frameindex = 1, not frameindex = index + 1

Can someone help me please?
Even a hack-solution using reflection would be OK (if using reflection is needed).

Answer (score 0):

There is a hack to a similar problem that could help you: [Pause a GIF in a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17545488/pause-a-gif-in-a-form).

Also, you could try resetting the images at the same time. Place the image in a temporary variable, assign both pictureboxes' images to null and then reassign the images at the same time.

Comment: Well, but I dont know which method should I call via reflection. I think Animate just runs and stops the animation.

Comment: Your second approach isnt also good for me, because when I reset both images, the user will see a frame-jump in the first (leading) image, which is always shown.

Answer (score 0):

a hack solution might be to offload the current images into temporary variables, set a temporary value for the image and then set it back to the temp variable. This forces each image to refresh from it's start point.

Just enumerate through each picturebox with that and it should refresh to be *almost* in sync, depending on how many you have and how long the operation takes I suppose.

assuming you have a picturebox named pic.

```
var loc = pic.ImageLocation;
pic.ImageLocation = "";
pic.ImageLocation = loc;
```